# tablesorter pagination does not sort on initial page load

Tags: jquery, pagination, tablesorter

I found a table sorter example that I am trying to use.

The table does not sort or go to next page on the first attempt when the page gets loaded. 
But if I change the limit and try to sort/go to next page  it works.
It does not throw any error either.

Here is the link:
http://srikanthrajan.com/test-table/tablesorter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey man see **working demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZK6dZ/

you had `LIMIT` value empty. : http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html

Rest demo should fit the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra']
    }).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
});​
```

Comment: Damn I'm slow. This is the answer, I've been debugging the tablesorter code to find the culprit and it's definitively the missing value in the pages select, "LIMIT" should have a value just like the others.

Comment: @Mahn `:))` Bazingaaa! `:P` Cheerios bruv!